# Created programs compiled with gcc using root,now I am into problems about not having execution permission & chmod gives .o file with EXE format error

Tags: c, linux, makefile, exec, chmod

I have simple code files and Makefile the generates some executable files. Now I am having problem with running it. First that the output of gcc is not giving me .o file with execution permission. Which is surprising,  at the bottom is my makefile I ran into these issues below.

With ls -lh command it says I only have maximum read and write permission to a writeshmem.o. same for all files in the directory. Even though I don't remember setting any system wide permission for outputting .o file without execution permission from gcc. And I DO NOT REMEMBER REVOKING ROOT USER PERMISSION.

```
root@fawad:/home/fawad/Desktop/Shared# ls -lh
total 44K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  263 Sep  6 14:07 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  359 Sep  6 14:10 destroy_shmem.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.9K Sep  6 14:10 destroy_shmem.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  381 Sep  6 13:40 readshmem.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.1K Sep  6 14:14 readshmem.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1014 Sep  6 11:58 shared_memory.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  267 Sep  6 14:09 shared_memory.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  490 Sep  6 13:30 writeshmem.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.2K Sep  6 14:14 writeshmem.o
```

As u can see there is no execution `x`

After above when I gave permission with

```
root@fawad:/home/fawad/Desktop/Shared# chmod +rwx writeshmem.o
```

I got this error

```
root@fawad:/home/fawad/Desktop/Shared# ./writeshmem.o 
bash: ./writeshmem.o: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

What that above error even means. It make no sense to me how giving permission to a file messed up with the EXecution format of the file. Someone can please explain why it matters for a file to cause this error. I only change the permission.

Makefile

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-g -Wall
OBJS=shared_memory.o
EXE=writeshmem.o readshmem.o destroy_shmem.o

all: $(EXE)

%.o: %.o $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< $(OBJS) -o $@
    
%.o: %.c %.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    
clean:
    rm .o $(EXE)
```

**Update**

after reading comment(`You should remove the .o from the executable names`) by kaylum I removed .o from executables in makefile But I still get error

```
root@fawad:/home/fawad/Desktop/Shared# ./writeshmem
bash: ./writeshmem: Permission denied
```

and same output from ls -lh

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  251 Sep  6 14:59 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.9K Sep  6 15:00 destroy_shmem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  359 Sep  6 14:10 destroy_shmem.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.1K Sep  6 15:00 readshmem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  381 Sep  6 13:40 readshmem.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1014 Sep  6 11:58 shared_memory.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  267 Sep  6 14:09 shared_memory.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.2K Sep  6 15:00 writeshmem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  490 Sep  6 13:30 writeshmem.c
```

everything including writeshmem is still with only rw permission and without x

Comment: `.o` files are not meant to be executable. They are binary files that are to be linked into a final executable but are not executable themselves.

Comment: Having two different `%.o` rules does not make sense like that. You should remove the `.o` from the executable names.

Comment: `You should remove the .o from the executable names.` the  will it work?

Comment: @kaylum after making changes which u mentioned removing .o from executables in makefile I still get permission error still only rw permission without x

Comment: Please show your new Makefile (add it, don't replace the old one). -- Delete all generated files and run "make". Post the output.

Comment: Each .c file should be compiled to a non-executable .o file. Then all the .o files are linked together to an executable not named .o. Normally, you use gcc for both steps.

Comment: @stark can u please direct me to a link on this doc where I can find documentation with example on       `Each .c file should be compiled to a non-executable .o file. Then all the .o files are linked together to an executable not named.o`  Like some specific chapter on this link    . I am expecting multiple .o files from my makefile, which I should get. The original one I got from the internet    https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

Comment: The example creates the executable named edit.  https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Simple-Makefile

Comment: Avoid doing work as root — the consequences of mistakes are often more serious than working as another user.